# Calling a method when thread terminates

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, methods

I have a form that starts a thread. Now I want the form to auto-close when this thread terminates.

The only solution I found so far is adding a timer to the form and check if thread is alive on every tick. But I want to know if there is a better way to do that?

Currently my code looks more less like this

```
partial class SyncForm : Form {
    Thread tr;

    public SyncForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void SyncForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Synchronize));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
        threadTimer.Start();
    }

    void threadTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!thread.IsAlive)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }

    void Synchronize()
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The BackgroundWorker class exists for this sort of thread management to save you having to roll your own; it offers a RunWorkerCompleted event which you can just listen for.

Answer (score 6):

Edit to make it call a helper method so it's cleaner.

```
thread = new Thread(() => { Synchronize(); OnWorkComplete(); });

...

private void OnWorkComplete()
{
    Close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the above methods has parameters and multiple threads. Sync(param1) takes 30 seconds, and when it executes OnWorkComplete i have paramx on the current param1 and i get wrong results :(

Comment: @Sakthivel, I think your issue is related to non local parameters. you need to create a local instance of your param1 before passing it to function for example `Synchronize`

Comment: @Okuma.Scott, why it dosn't work? I don't have linq but I do have .NET 4 and it is working

Comment: My only issue is how to pass param from `Sync` to `Complete`

Answer (score 6):

If you have a look at a BackgroundWorker, there is a RunWorkerCompleted event that is called when the worker completes.

For more info on BackgroundWorkers [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

**Or**

You could add a call to a complete function from the Thread once it has finished, and invoke it.

```
void Synchronize()
{
    //DoWork();
    //FinishedWork();
}

void FinishedWork()
{
if (InvokeRequired == true)
  {
  //Invoke
  }
else
  {
  //Close
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at delegates, IAsyncResult, BeginInvoke and AsyncCallback

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your thread method, you can call Close() using the Invoke() method (because most WinForms methods should be called from the UI thread):

```
public void Synchronize()
{
   Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Close));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for arbitrary thread (e.g. started by some other code), using [UnmanagedThreadUtils](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedThreadUtils/) package:

```
// Use static field to make sure that delegate is alive.
private static readonly UnmanagedThread.ThreadExitCallback ThreadExitCallbackDelegate = OnThreadExit;

public static void Main()
{
    var threadExitCallbackDelegatePtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(ThreadExitCallbackDelegate);
    var callbackId = UnmanagedThread.SetThreadExitCallback(threadExitCallbackDelegatePtr);

    for (var i = 1; i <= ThreadCount; i++)
    {
        var threadLocalVal = i;

        var thread = new Thread(_ =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Managed thread #{threadLocalVal} started.");
            UnmanagedThread.EnableCurrentThreadExitEvent(callbackId, new IntPtr(threadLocalVal));
        });

        thread.Start();
    }

    UnmanagedThread.RemoveThreadExitCallback(callbackId);
}

private static void OnThreadExit(IntPtr data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Unmanaged thread #{data.ToInt64()} is exiting.");
}
```